# Write txt file into a 2d array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm new to python and I'm trying read in this file into a 2d array.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                  x
x       xxx        x
x       x xxxxx    x
x   s     x        x
x       x x  xxxxxxx
x  xx xxxxx        x
x      x      g    x
x      x           x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I tried to do this with numpy library but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: tried to do.. how? show a code what you have tried.

Comment: 2 for loops, 1 looping over rows, the other over elements. In the beginning of each row, create new array. Per X or ' ', add some symbol to array

Comment: `np.array([list(row) for row in data.splitlines()])`

Comment: This isn't a standard input format.  So just use standard Python code to create a list of lists of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what kind of array you want to create.

Here some demo with a low-level approach (assuming more) and a more high-level approach following Jeronimo's comment.

The low-level approach uses ASCII-definitions (and may be dependent on the editor / program created this file).

Ascii:

- 10: new line
- 13: carriage return
- 120: x
- ...

Code:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=120)

""" Hacky low-level approach """
with open('input_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    mat = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint8)
    col_len = np.where(mat != 120)[0][0]  # assumes:
                                          # - constant row-len
                                          # - full # first line
    mat = mat[np.logical_and(mat != 10,  mat != 13)].reshape(-1,col_len)

    print(mat)
    print(mat.view('c'))

""" Recommended """
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    mat = np.array([list(row[:-1]) for row in f.readlines()])
    # -1 for removing new-line
    print(mat)
```

Output:

```
[[120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120]
 [120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120]
 [120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120 120 120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120]
 [120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120  32 120 120 120 120 120  32  32  32  32 120]
 [120  32  32  32 115  32  32  32  32  32 120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120]
 [120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120  32 120  32  32 120 120 120 120 120 120 120]
 [120  32  32 120 120  32 120 120 120 120 120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120]
 [120  32  32  32  32  32  32 120  32  32  32  32  32  32 103  32  32  32  32 120]
 [120  32  32  32  32  32  32 120  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 120]
 [120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120]]
[[b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x' b'x' b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x' b' ' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b's' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x' b' ' b'x' b' ' b' ' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b'x' b'x' b' ' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'g' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x']
 [b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b' ' b'x']
 [b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x' b'x']]
[['x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x' 'x' 'x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x' ' ' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' ' ' 's' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x' ' ' 'x' ' ' ' ' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' 'x' 'x' ' ' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'g' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x']
 ['x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'x']
 ['x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x' 'x']]
```